# Is there a way to quickly ignore all future email from a sender in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

There are some companies that will email me and make it nearly impossible to unsubscribe.

I'm looking for a way to create a rule to auto-archive or delete their email. The problem is that creating a rule like that takes too long and gets me out of the flow of answering email.

Is there a way to quickly create this kind of rule -- ideally with a single click?

Comment: Why exactly that's a problem? I'd look for greasemonkey scripts or make one if I were you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

more actions-> filter messages like these

The follow the on screen instructions (note there is a test filter option)

http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78127

Answer (score 6):

A single click option would be to use the 'Report Spam' button;

[image: Gmail Report Spam Button]

http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=6602

> To remove spam from your inbox:
>
> 1. Select the unwanted messages.
> 2. Click Report Spam.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Within the last year or so, Gmail has added the ability to block email addresses.

Simply open the message menu and choose "block this address". This will add the email address to a special list (found where you keep your filters) and will cause all future messages from that address be sent directly to spam.